# Google Appscript doGet() doesn't return parameters, but returns html of web app

Tags: google-apps-script

I feel like I'm totally missing something about how to get back the results from a function call to a doGet() Google appscript. Please can anyone suggest what I'm doing wrong.

Using a HTTP GET request all I get back is the entire html content from the app and the doGet() hasn't executed.

my doGet() looks like this.

```
function doGet(e) {
  var params = JSON.stringify(e);
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(params);
}
```

The returned data looks like this.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you are looking for `ContentService` rather than `HtmlService`

Something along the lines of this:

```
function doPost(e) {
  return ContentService.createTextOutput(JSON.stringify(e))
}
```

HtmlService will output a HTML page

**Authorization**
Also, make sure you have "anyone even anonymous" can run the web app option selected under "Publish>Deploy>Web app" Window.